# Проблема в Xcode c MessageInputBar

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, messenger, cocoapods

Постоянно вылезает ошибка "Use of undeclared type" прочитал, что после обновления MessageKit нежно установить MessageInputBar, но проблема осталась, подскажите, в чём проблема ? [image: MessageInputBar][image: 2][image: 3]

Comment: Какие import в вашем файле?

Comment: Да, похоже проблема с import. Если вы используете типы данных или методы из фреймворков, то вы должны их явно добавить через import. Например, import MapKit для карт и т.д.